# Flutter - No permission found in the manifest for [] 15

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions, storage

```
  Future<void> _checkPermission() async {
// final micPermissionStatus = await Permission.microphone.request();
// if (micPermissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
//   throw Exception('Recording permission required.');
// }
// final storagePermissionStatus =
//     await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
// if (storagePermissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
//   throw Exception('Storage permission required.');
// }

Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
  Permission.microphone,
  Permission.storage,
].request();
print(statuses[Permission.storage]);
}
```

Calling _checkPermissions in init:

```
  Future<void> initPlugin() async {
_checkPermission();
....
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.voice_recorder">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  

<application
    android:label="voice_recorder"
 
  ....
```

What is going on? What permission does it not find?

I have already tried flutter clean, uninstall/reinstall, restart 4-5 times.

Comment: Make sure you have add permission in correct manifest file 
android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest. also try to clean project.

Comment: yaaa, checked that too...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the storage permissions in your Manifest.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

All the permissions in Manifest,

```xml
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: But this is already there in the manifest... Do you mean just this and remove other 2?

Comment: Yes. Also your permission has `Manifest.`.

Comment: I updated the answer to include all permissions.

Comment: Nothing changes. Still the same error.

Comment: What's the log?

Comment: Having similar error, any luck?

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.